# Reading S3 data from Google's dataproc

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm running a pyspark application through Google's dataproc on a cluster I created.  In one stage, the application needs to access a directory in an Amazon S3 directory.  At that stage, I get the error:

AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be specified as the username or password (respectively) of a s3 URL, or by setting the fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId or fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively).

I logged onto the headnode of the cluster and set the /etc/boto.cfg with my AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY information, but that didn't solve the access issue.

(1) Any other suggestions for how to access AWS S3 from a dataproc cluster?

(2) Also, what is the name of the user that dataproc uses to access the cluster?  If I knew that, I could set the ~/.aws directory on the cluster for that user.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you shelling out from your job to use something like the `awscli` or are you accessing S3 through normal Spark/Hadoop FileSystem interfaces?

Comment: accessing s3 through normal spark interfaces.  i basically want to set the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and then do a sc.textFile(s3_path) and get the count

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using the Hadoop/Spark interfaces (like `sc.textFile`), everything should indeed be done through the `fs.s3.*` or `fs.s3n.*` or `fs.s3a.*` keys rather than trying to wire through any `~/.aws` or `/etc/boto.cfg` settings. There are a few ways you can plumb those settings through to your Dataproc cluster:

At cluster creation time:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create --properties \
    core:fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId=<s3AccessKey>,core:fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey=<s3SecretKey> \
    --num-workers ...
```

The `core` prefix here indicates you want the settings to be placed in the `core-site.xml` file, as explained in the [Cluster Properties documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/cluster-properties).

Alternatively, at job-submission time, if you're using Dataproc's APIs:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster <your-cluster> \
    --properties spark.hadoop.fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId=<s3AccessKey>,spark.hadoop.fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey=<s3SecretKey> \
    ...
```

In this case, we're passing the properties through as Spark properties, and Spark provides a handy mechanism to define "hadoop" conf properties as a subset of Spark conf, simply using the `spark.hadoop.*` prefix. If you're submitting at the command line over SSH, this is equivalent to:

```
spark-submit --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId=<s3AccessKey> \
    --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey=<s3SecretKey>
```

Finally, if you want to set it up at cluster creation time but prefer not to have your access keys explicitly set in your Dataproc metadata, you might opt to use an [initialization action](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/init-actions) instead. There's a handy tool called `bdconfig` that should be present on the path with which you can modify XML settings easily:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Create this shell script, name it something like init-aws.sh
bdconfig set_property \
    --configuration_file /etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml \
    --name 'fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId' \
    --value '<s3AccessKey>' \
    --clobber
bdconfig set_property \
    --configuration_file /etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml \
    --name 'fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey' \
    --value '<s3SecretKey>' \
    --clobber
```

Upload that to a GCS bucket somewhere, and use it at cluster creation time:

```
gsutil cp init-aws.sh gs://<your-bucket>/init-aws.sh
gcloud dataproc clustres create --initialization-actions \
    gs://<your-bucket>/init-aws.sh
```

While Dataproc metadata is indeed encrypted at rest and heavily secured just like any other user data, using the init action instead helps prevent inadvertently showing your access key/secret for example to someone standing behind your screen when viewing your Dataproc cluster properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with setting the AWS config, while initialization of sparkContext.

```
conf = < your SparkConf()>
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", <s3AccessKey>)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", <s3SecretKey>)
```

Comment: I get the error: AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'hadoopConfiguration'.  This job is a spark job without hadoop.  Is there a way to set this config without hadoop?