# configuration for `spark.hadoop.fs.s3` gets applied to `fs.s3a` not `fs.s3`

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, google-cloud-dataproc

I have read the answer posted on [how to configure s3 access keys for dataproc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377635/reading-s3-data-from-googles-dataproc) but I have find it dissatisfactory.

Reason is because when I follow the steps and set hadoop conf for `spark.hadoop.fs.s3`, `s3://...` path still have access issue while as `s3a://...` path works.  Test spark-shell run can be seen below.

s3 vs s3n vs s3a is topic of it's own, although I guess we don't have to worry about s3n.  But I find it strange that configuration application to `s3` is manifest for `s3a`.

here are my questions:

1. is this dataproc or spark?  I'm assuming spark considering spark-shell is having this issue.
2. is there a way to configure `s3` from spark-submit conf flags without code change?
3. Is this a bug or are we now preferring `s3a` over `s3?

Thanks,

```
***@!!!:~$ spark-shell --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId=CORRECT_ACCESS_KEY \
>     --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey=SECRETE_KEY

// Try to read existing path, which breaks...
scala> spark.read.parquet("s3://bucket/path/to/folder")
17/06/01 16:19:58 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource: Error while looking for metadata directory.
java.io.IOException: /path/to/folder doesn't exist
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.Jets3tFileSystemStore.get(Jets3tFileSystemStore.java:170)
  ...

// notice `s3` not `s3a`
scala> spark.conf.getAll("spark.hadoop.fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId")
res3: String = CORRECT_ACCESS_KEY

scala> spark.conf.getAll("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId")
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId
  at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
  at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
  at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:59)
  ... 48 elided

scala> sc
res5: org.apache.spark.SparkContext = org.apache.spark.SparkContext@426bf2f2

scala> sc.hadoopConfiguration
res6: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration = Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml, hdfs-default.xml, hdfs-site.xml, file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-site.xml

scala> sc.hadoopConfiguration.get("fs.s3.access.key")
res7: String = null   <--- ugh... wtf?

scala> sc.hadoopConfiguration.get("fs.s3n.access.key")
res10: String = null  <--- I understand this...

scala> sc.hadoopConfiguration.get("fs.s3a.access.key")
res8: String = CORRECT_ACCESS_KEY  <--- But what is this???

// Successfull file read
scala> spark.read.parquet("s3a://bucket/path/to/folder")
ivysettings.xml file not found in HIVE_HOME or HIVE_CONF_DIR,/etc/hive/conf.dist/ivysettings.xml will be used
res9: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [whatev... ... 22 more fields]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some magic in spark-submit which picks up your `AWS_` env vars and sets them for {s3, s3n, s3a} filesystens; that may be what's happening under the hood.

There is *not* any magic copying of the s3a settings from the s3a to s3n options in the Hadoop JARs, or anywhere else, so it may be some of the -site.xml files that is defining it.

Do use s3a:// if you have the Hadoop 2.7.x JARs on your CP anyway: better performance. V4 API auth (mandatory for some regions), ongoing maintenance.

Comment: moving to s3a:// is totally fine for us and we can make that change, it just that configuration application is bit unexpected.  Another complication is that within EMR `s3` is preferred over `s3a` for "complition sake", whatever the f that means...

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-file-system-s3/

Comment: Amazon EMR's s3: != ASF s3:// client; it's more a fork/rewrite of s3n, with lots of changes we know not of. s3a is the ASF one optimised GET-by-GET for max performance on Hive/Spark/MapReduce queries against ORC & Parquet data. FWIW, the S3 SDK team to talk to us...

Comment: Yes we have been warned over that and had internal discussions about AWS's deviation.  I guess you mean s3 SDK team is talking to you guys but if you need someone to testify let me know... :D